# Keep 'transform-scale' aspect ratio for iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, aspect-ratio

I'm having trouble keeping the '**transform-scale**' attribute on an *aspect ratio* when the browser window is being resized. For instance, if the window was resized, the iframe with the transform-scale attribute would scale the contents inside to fit the iframe width and height without resizing anything of the sites contents. I can't seem to understand how I could achieve this without using JavaScript or any other Libraries. This is what I came up with below:

HTML:

```
<div>
<iframe id="resize" src="http://www.w3schools.com/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    height: 100vw;
    width: 56.25vw;
    /* 100/56.25 = 1.778 */
    background: skyblue;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 177.78vh;
    /* 16/9 = 1.778 */
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    /* vertical center */
    left:0;
    right:0;
    /* horizontal center */
}
iframe {
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform-scale(0.8);
    -o-transform: scale(0.8);
    -ms-zoom: 0.8;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rkmyc95e/1/

All I'm trying to do is maintain the '**transform-scale**' aspect ratio when the window is scaled.

NOTE: As you can see, I'm also having issues maintaining the aspect ratio of the iframe, I can't maintain the top and bottom to stay in place.

Answer (score 1):

The transform scale you are using is just going to set the width of the iframe to be 80% of its width, and the height of the iframe to be 80% of its height. And won't help you with maintaining an aspect ratio.

You have the iframe set to be 100% of its parent width and height on the iframe element in html. If you remove those two attributes, you'll see something interesting, a starting point for fixed aspect ratio that you can start working with.

To then maintain aspect ratio of either the div or the iframe, check out a common question on SE like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/3708223

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately that doesn't help me maintain the aspect ratio for the iframes 'transform-scale' attribute.

Comment: I think you might be confused about what transform scale does. You can transform the x and y scale separately, but setting transform scale to a single value will always maintain whatever ratio already existed between the element's height and width.

Comment: Yes, but how could I force the attribute to change value based on the iframes aspect ratio?

Comment: Any solutions to this?